# python need to convert a "linspace" into something more "logarithmic"

Tags: python, numpy

Forgive me, I'm always been very bad at math, now trying to learn some python (and some math aswell) by coding.

I have this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

whole = 1 # percentage: 1 = 100%, 0.1 = 10% ecc 
nparts = 10 # how many "steps" we want to use
origin = 100 # starting value we

ranged = origin * whole # defining the percentage of our starting value

values = np.linspace(origin - ranged/2, origin + ranged/2, nparts * 2)

r = []
g = []
for v in values:
    if v > origin:
        r.append(v)
        #reds = f"{v} is {100*(v - origin)/origin}% of {origin}"
        #print(reds)

    else:
        g.append(v)
        #greens = f"{v} is {100*(v - origin)/origin}% of {origin}"
        #print(greens)
        
        
print("reds")
print(r)
print("greens")
print(g)
```

These last `print(g) and print(r)` output the numerical results.

If I plot this, you can clearly see what this does.

```
axes = plt.gca()

#origin BLUE 
plt.axhline(y=origin, color='b', linestyle='-')

#reds
for i in r:
        plt.axhline(y=i, color='r', linestyle='-')
#greens
for i in g:
        plt.axhline(y=i, color='g', linestyle='-')
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPVuu.png)

So as you can see given an `origin` (blue line) and giving a +/- percentage `whole` it creates n lines ( `nparts` ) both `reds if they are > origin` and `green if < origin` spreading them linearly `values = np.linspace(origin - ranged/2, origin + ranged/2, nparts * 2)`
on this `whole` percentage from the `origin` value

now my question is: how can I spread those lines on a logarithmic way (don't get me wrong, I'm so bad at math I don't even know if what I'm looking for is logarithmic-related)
I would like to achieve something like this (I did photoshop the plotted image).
I would really love to keep that `whole` and maybe being able to add a new `variable` to "control" this logarithmic spreading

basically I need to find a way to find another function to replace `values = np.linspace(origin - ranged/2, origin + ranged/2, nparts * 2)` to achieve the desired result attached below.
I tried both np.geomspace and np.logspace without any success, maybe I'm just bad or maybe I need to find another way to do this.

Desired result:
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfn4l.png)

Can you help me solve this out?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass any `linspace` to `np.log`. This will give the logarithm of each point. To get the result within certain bounds, you can use a linear transformation: divide by the largest value and multiply with the desired range, perhaps add a baseline value.

For example:

```py
values = np.log(np.linspace(1, 10, nparts))

r = 150 - 50 * (values / values[-1])
g =  50 + 50 * (values / values[-1])
```

This will result in the following plot:

[image: logplot]

If you need to include the `origin` and `whole` variables, here's one way to do that:

```py
values = np.log(np.linspace(1, 10, nparts))
half_range = origin * whole / 2

g = origin + half_range * (1 - values / values[-1])
r = origin * 2 - g
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried this out but I can't make it work. When I change the "whole" variable everything messes up.

Comment: @mosf I've added a paragraph about that.

Comment: to be clear: 
Origin is the starting point, whatever number.. let's say it is 2198.
whole is another number that gives me a range (percentile) to create the limits.
Let's say whole is 0.2 (20%).
My code needs to create a range between +10% and -10% (total 20%) from the origin point. 
So if i change the whole number to let's say 0.12 it will create a range +6% and -6% from the origin point. Is it clear now?

Comment: Let's say whole is 0.2 (20%). And origin is 100. origin + (origin * whole)/2 = my upper limit = 100 + 10 = 110, origin - (origin * whole)/2 = my lower limit = 100 - 10 = 90,  So from origin to my upper limit (100 -> 110) i need to create "nparts" * red lines, and from origin to my lower limit (100 -> 90) I need to create "nparts" * green lines

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I understand it now I think. I've edited the last code block in my answer.

Comment: This looks like it's working perfectly. Thanks a lot!